# Table relation error value not within the range

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

Ax 2012 R3.  I’ve created a new table to hold group data (let’s call it AgencyTable); I’ve created a RefRecId that references AgencyTable and extends RefRecId (lets call it AgencyTableRefRecId).

I’ve created another new table called RatingsTable, to which I’ve added the AgencyTableRefRecId.  The RatingsTable has a relation to the AgencyTable on the AgencyTableRefRecId (Cardinality = OneMore; RelatedTableCardinality = ExactlyOne; RelationshipType = Association).
I’ve also added a reference in RatingsTable  to the BankAccountTable and created a relation on the BankAccountId.

I have an AgencyTable record.  When I create a record in the RatingsTable, and click the field that references the AgencyTable, I get a dropdown and can see the AgencyTable record, but when I select the record I get error: “The value is not within the range.  Acceptable values are in the range -9223372036854775808 - 9223372036854775808” (the max and min of int64).

This is such a simple relation and common way of relating data.  I’ve checked my edt; I’ve checked the relation and can’t find what is causing the problem. (The relation to BankAccount works fine).

The datadictionary has been sync’ed.  The AOS was recently restarted.
What is causing the issue?

Comment: RelatedTableCardinality should be ZeroOrMany

Comment: No (I presume you mean the Carinality, since there is on property for RelatedTableCardinality for ZeroOrMany).  And the Cardinality cannot be Zero since a record in RatingsTable cannot exist without an Agency.

Answer (score 1):

It is important the relation to `AgencyTable` is created as as ForeignKey relation to the primary key.

If the relation to extended data type is created correctly you will be prompted to create the relation when you drag and drop it to the `RatingsTable` field node.
If you answer *Yes*, it will be created correctly.

Also the form control should be of type "Reference group" to work as expected, this is not the case if you use the table browser.

Comment: I did create a Foreign key relation.  
I’ve found the issue.  When I dragged the edt that is a refRecId of the AgencyTable into the RatingsTable, I was prompted by Ax and asked if I wanted to create a relation, to which I said yes. 
I incorrectly assumed that the relation would be created on the RecId, but it was created on the AgencyId (which is a alfpnumeric value field, and which is the Primary index of the AgencyTable).
So the mistake is simple, always check the relations that Ax builds, and make sure that it is correct.